# Providing latitude/longitude to google RESTful search API

Tags: rest, geolocation, google-api

I have been trying to find a search implementation that is able to consistently provide good quality results for local searches, and after much mucking about, I've discovered it is possible to use local search via Google's RESTful API.

For instance this URL:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=skydiving&near=new%20york%20ny
```

Provides a list of skydiving centers near `New York, NY`.

However, finding this out has been pure experimentation, as I've yet to find any documentation on local search REST features/parameters.

Does anyone know if it is possible to provide a Latitude/Longitude, rather than a city/state?

Comment: If your scope and searches are a lot in number then i would recommend you to use OpenStreetMap api's and work on it because its an open source project and it does not have any limit on number of query per day. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6

Comment: I was under the impression that Google's RESTful API didn't have any usage limits?